# Since For loops is n Timecomplexity So is it Better To Use Only couts for example in cpp and never use for loops?

Tags: c++

in algorithms Complexity
For loops is N Time complex
Nested For loop Is n2 time complex
but cout in cpp or printf in c and cpp is Constant time Complex So its faster
so is it Better To use Cout 10 times to print number1to10 since its Actually faster ?
or ? (We should use Only for loops when Its really hard to code it for example 1k line of code or something!);

like

```
cout<<1;
cout<<2;
cout<<3;
cout<<4;
```

and so on
Instead of

```
for(int i=1;i<=10;i++){
cout<<i<<" ";
}
```

its a Beginner Question(so sorry if its  weird) but it just got into my Head and i literally couldn't find any answer to it And tried to search for it But i found nothing!

Comment: Have you tried to benchmark both approaches, to see if you can tell any difference in performance on your modern multi-Ghz CPU?

Comment: i know it wouldn't make any big difference but idk why i thought it would be better to use cout billion time in 2022 XDD anyway thanks

Comment: What, exactly, does "better" mean, then?

Comment: i thought like Faster==Better doesn't matter how much lines do u type ;

Comment: i think i have to learn more about this i just learnt Time complexity so yeah but tbh Thanks i will try to understand Time Complexity Better

Comment: @TarekHassan algorithmic complexity is about performance within specific parameters, not speed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you copy and paste a printout *n* times then the code still takes *O*(*n*) time. Unrolling the loop doesn't change the fact that you've got *n* printouts. Except now you have *O*(*n*) lines of code instead of the *O*(1) lines of a `for` loop.